# jquery.jscrollpane.js yields alternating line-up of divs when sortable elements are dragged

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-jscrollpane

Note:  post edited 7/27/2017 to include (at the end of the post) the solution to the issue in this case.

I am working with an audio-player module using Joomla.  I have solved a number of issues but this one is being persistent.  The playlist doesn't load (causing the page-load to never complete) unless the file **jquery.jscrollpane.js** is included in the page.  When the page first loads, there is the following line-up of divs...

```
div.componentPlaylist
    div.playlist_inner
```

After re-ordering the list by dragging any of the elements in it to a new position **an even number of times** the **same** line-up of divs is generated.

After re-ordering the list by dragging any of the elements in it to a new position **an odd number of times** the line-up of divs **changes** to...

```
div.componentPlaylist
    div.jspContainer
        div.jspPane
            div.playlist_inner
```

A possibly relevant factor here is that I don't really want the scrollable feature.  The height of the playlist is set to auto, rather than a pixel size, so everything fits just right without a scrollbar.

I would like to know where to focus my attention in the file **jquery.jscrollpane.js** to get a consistent line-up of divs, either with or without the two inner ones, regardless of how many times the list is re-ordered by dragging (including zero).

Edited 7/27/2017

Issue solved by commenting-out one line in the file - the one-line entire contents inside curly braces under "destroy: function()".  This causes the 4-div line-up to appear from the first page load and remain thereafter.